# What's the proper environment for a Land Shark? (Cthonic template summon monster shark)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning

*"... the Land Shark is considered the cleverest of all sharks. Unlike the Great White shark, which tends to inhabit the waters and harbors of recreational beach areas, the Land Shark may strike at any place, any time."*

When you cast a summon monster spell with the feat Versatile Summon monster, you may apply a simple template to the creature; one of which is "Cthonic". This makes the creature into an earth creature, able to burrow through the earth.

Can you add this template to an aquatic animal such as a shark, and summon it on land? 
What are the interactions of having the earth subtype and an aquatic subtype?

---

For reference:

"Creatures cannot be summoned into an environment that cannot support them."
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/versatile-summon-monster/
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-template-chthonic-creature-cr-0-or-1

Comment: Tangentially to your question, landsharks already exist in Pathfinder. We just call them [Bulletes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/bulette/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

A [Shark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/shark/shark) has the [aquatic subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Aquatic-Subtype).

> These creatures always have swim speeds and can move in water without making Swim checks. **An aquatic creature can breathe water. It cannot breathe air unless it has the amphibious special quality.** Aquatic creatures always treat Swim as a class skill.

Emphasis mine.

The [earth subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Earth) does not change the fact that the shark can only breathe water.

> This subtype is usually used for outsiders with a connection to the Elemental Planes of Earth. Earth creatures usually have burrow speeds, and most earth creatures can burrow through solid rock. Earth creatures with a burrow speed possess tremorsense.

So, since the shark cannot breathe air, the environment cannot support them.

If it was ruled that the environment *could* support them (i.e. that the environment doesn't support the creature is a purely spatial restriction), they would immediately start suffocating.

In general, it seems that most creatures need to hold their breath while burrowing. For example, the spell [Earth Glide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/earth-glide/) specifically calls out that it does not give the ability to breathe underground. Contrast this with the [Oracle's Earth Glide *(Su)* ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/stone/) which calls out that one *can* breathe stone.

Comment: I think you made a typo; it says "the fact that the shark can only breathe air".

Comment: What if it was underwater underground?  Like in moist earth/quicksand or something.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Maybe a separate question, if it has not been asked already.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that "Land Shark" (note capitalization) is a nick name for the Bullette, a creature unique from a shark?